# ¿Cómo configurar los atajos de teclado en intellij-idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, atajo

Quiero saber si se puede configurar los atajos de teclado en intellij-idea y quisiera saber como hacerlo, eh buscado tutoriales y no puedo ver uno sobre ese tema, ya que en devc++ podía hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En éste enlace jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html, podemos encontrar las configuraciones de atajos de teclado para intellij-idea en donde dentro de nuestro IDE presionamos las teclas Ctrl+Alt+S y seleccionando "keymap"(mapa de teclas) luego seleccionas "Editor Actions" (Acciones del Editor), buscas el atajo de teclado que quieres cambiarle las teclas de acceso, seleccionas el lápiz y lo configuras, de esta manera se puede cambiar los atajos del teclado, para este IDE de Intellij-idea.

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ IDEA ofrece varias posibilidades para aprender atajos:

**Buscar acción** es el comando más importante que le permite buscar comandos y configuraciones en todos los menús y herramientas.

Presione `Ctrl+Shift+A` y comience a escribir para obtener una lista de acciones sugeridas. Luego seleccione la acción necesaria y presione `Enter` para ejecutarla.

En la página oficial de IntelliJ IDEA podrás entrar información más detallada para empezar con todo lo que necesitas: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Espero haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: Gracias por éste enlace https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html, ya que la respuesta a mi pregunta la saqué de allí y es esta :                                                                                                                Presione `Ctrl+Alt+S`y seleccione "keymap"(mapa de teclas) luego seleccionas "Editor Actions" (Acciones del Editor), buscas el atajo de teclado que quieres cambiar teclas de acceso, seleccionas el lápiz y lo configuras.